# how to prevent only one view from rotating on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

i have a tabbar application and as you may know, you have to return YES in the `shouldAutorotate` method in every view controller for the views to be able to rotate. My  problem is that i want to prevent a view from rotating and if i return NO then the other views won't rotate either. Is there a work around for this? **Info:** i'm not subclassing UITabbarController in any of my views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could check in shouldAutorotate what the current view is:

```
if ( currentView == viewThatShouldNotRotate )
    return NO;
```

However, `shouldAutorotate` is only called when changing the view controller. If you want only one view to autorotate, consider giving it its own view controller that the `UITabBarController` can present as a modal view. You'll have to handle the navigation logic yourself though.

Comment: Can i have two xib files for the same view controller. I mean if the phone is in landscape i could change to a different view xib (not a view controller) Changing to a new view controller will make me copy the same code to the next view controller.

Comment: By 'giving it its own view controller', I meant that you should call `presentModalViewController` on the `UITabBarController` with the view controller that you want to be displayed in portrait or in landscape mode. The `UITabBarController` should return `YES` in `shouldAutorotate` for portrait only, while the modal controller should return `YES` for both portrait and landscape. Write code in the `layoutSubviews` selector of your view class to actually rearrange the view for landscape or portrait view, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ShouldAutoRotateToInterFaceOrientation: method

```
 [self.navigationController 
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```